# Assign value to a column based on values of other columns in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with columns Date and Order. I want to add a column named Batch to this table which will be filled as follows: For each Date, we start from the first Order, and group each two orders in one batch.

It means that for records with Date = 1 in this example (the first 4 records), the first two records (Order= 10 and Order=30) will have batch number: Batch = 1, the next two records (Order = 80 and Order = 110) will have Batch = 2, and so on.

If at the end the number of remaining record(s) is less than the batch size (2 in this example), 
the remained order(s) will have a separate Batch number, as in the example below, number of records with Date=2 is odd, so the last record (5th records) will have Batch = 3.

```
Date  Order
-----------
1      10

1      30

1      80

1      110

2      20

2      30

2      50

2      70

2      120

3      90

Date  Order Batch
------------------
1      10     1

1      30     1

1      80     2

1      110    2

2      20     1

2      30     1

2      50     2

2      70     2

2      120    3

3      90     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the analytic function row_number to get row numbers 1,2,3,... within each date. Then add one and divide by two:

```
select 
  dateid, 
  orderid, 
  trunc((row_number() over (partition by dateid order by orderid) +1 ) / 2) as batch
from mytable;
```

Comment: Sorry for the very basic question. Why do I get "single-row subquery returns more than one row" error message when I run this query?`update mytable set batch=(select 
  trunc((row_number() over (partition by dateid order by orderid) +1 ) / 2) from mytable`);

Comment: Because you select all records of the table in the inner query. You only want to select one record for each updating record. You need a where clause in your inner select restricting it to the key of the updating record.